# array each file upload foreach into single string

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, implode

I a building a uploader and need some help if possible. I have an uploader that a person can add as many pictures as they want to the multi uploader with a javascript field adder.

[image]

I want echo all the images he uploaded as text, but using `$fileName[0]`, `$fileName[1]`, `$fileName[2]` i dont think will work because its not certain how many they will upload. Is there an array I can use to implode or join all arrays to show into one.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['addpart'])) {

    $image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $name  = $_POST['username'];
    $name  = str_replace(' ', '_', $name);
    $i     = 0;
    $i2    = 1;
    $id    = uniqid();

    foreach ($image as $key) {
        $fileData   = pathinfo(basename($_FILES["images"]["name"][$i]));
        $fileName[] = $name . '_' . $id . '_' . $i2 . '.' . $fileData['name'] . 'jpg';
        move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . end($fileName));
        //copy("image/" . end($fileName) , "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName));
        $images     = "image/" . end($fileName);
        $new_images = "image_thumbnail/" . end($fileName);
        $width      = 100; //*** Fix Width & Heigh (Autu caculate) ***//
        $size       = GetimageSize($images);
        $height     = round($width * $size[1] / $size[0]);

        switch ($size[2]) {
            case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
                $images_orig = imagecreatefromgif($images);
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
                $images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
                break;

            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
                $images_orig = imagecreatefrompng($images);
                break;

            default:
                die("Unknown filetype");
        }

        //$images_orig = imagecreatefromjpeg($images);
        $photoX     = ImagesX($images_orig);
        $photoY     = ImagesY($images_orig);
        $images_fin = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
        ImageCopyResampled($images_fin, $images_orig, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width + 1, $height + 1, $photoX, $photoY);
        ImageJPEG($images_fin, $new_images);
        $i++;
        $i2++;
    }

    echo 'Uploaded<br />';
    echo 'Main Image - <a href="image/' . $fileName[0] . '">' . $fileName[0] . '</a><br />';
    echo 'Extra Image 1 - <a href="image/' . $fileName[1] . '">' . $fileName[1] . '</a><br />';
    echo 'Extra Image 2 - <a href="image/' . $fileName[2] . '">' . $fileName[2] . '</a><br />';
    echo '<hr>';
}

?>
```

I hope what i am asking is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [foreach loop](http://php.net/manual/it/control-structures.foreach.php) and cycle through all the items in `$fileName`

```
foreach ($fileName as $file) {

    echo "Value: $file<br />\n";

}
```

In this example, what you refer to as `$fileName[0]`, `$fileName[1]`, ..., in your question is simply called `$file`. The foreach loop will take care of counting the items inside of `$fileName`, so that you don't necessarily have to know it.

Because of this, I might suggest you to rename `$fileName` to `$fileNames` (since it is an array) and write the foreach like this: `($fileNames as $fileName)`.

---

For other purposes, if you need to know how many items there are in an array you can use [count()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.count.php).

Comment: @Saturnix Thanks for the help, I got that code to work!, `foreach ($fileName as $item) { echo $item.','; }`, I also made it so it adds a coma to them. one more question, how could I remove the last comma that trails at the end?

Comment: use an if statement to check if it is the last element.

Comment: thanks I realize I had to implode the array with commas.